# Indian Passport. Missing entry stamp into USA

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, visa-extensions, h1b-visas

I recently traveled from India to USA. I am on H1B.
I entered USA on 29th December 2016. As my Visa extension is due in August 2017, I was gathering documents for Visa Extension. It was required to provide a scanned copy of passport page with all entry and exit stamps.

Myself and my wife both travelled back from India. My wife's passport has a entry stamp with date as 29th December 2016. But the same is missing from my passport. I guess the officer missed putting the entry stamp on my passport. My I 94 reflects the correct date of entry as 29th December.
Somehow I still have my boarding pass from this trip (usually I throw them once trip is complete).

1. Want to know what could be implications of missing entry stamp when I travel to India next time (somewhere towards early next year)?
2. Does this impact my H1B Visa extension ?
3. Also what can I do to correct this information on my passport?

Comment: Want to know what could be implications of missing entry stamp when I travel to India next time (somewhere towards early next year)?     **None**! You have the I-94 as proof.     
Does this impact my H1B Visa extension ? **NO**!      
Also what can I do to correct this information on my passport? Nothing required to _correct_. You can contact Customs and Border Patrol for [Deferred Inspection](https://www.cbp.gov/contact/deferred-inspection/overview-deferred-inspection) if you still are agonizing.

Comment: @SheikPaul So is it that entry stamp is not a requirement? I know you answered, but want to confirm again.
Because when I travelled back from USA to India, at the exit of USA airport the officer wrote the exit date just below the entry stamp. So if next time when I am travelling back to India, do you mean, is it sufficient to show I94 to the officer?

Comment: @Versatile: Who are you going to show an I-94 to while _traveling back to India_? The US does not have exit inspections.

Comment: @HenningMakholm When I recently traveled back to India, at USA airport, before luggage screening there is a officer who will check your passport. That officer wrote the exit date, on which I was going to exit USA, just below the entry stamp. As my passport does not have an entry stamp for 29th December, what will such a officer who looks at your passport, will do this time. He may need a reference to look at when I entered. Where will he write the date on which I am exiting USA.

Comment: @Versatile The I94 you have provides the same information, which is your entry date and status in which you entered. I was a visitor, F1, H1B, Permanent Resident before becoming a citizen so I understand you not taking any chances. The stamp is NOT required. Back in the day they stamped the I-94 and attached to your passport. It was quick proof to anyone that you entered legally. They have all that information however USCIS is notoriously lazy so even when you apply for something else, they like you to provide the same evidence **they have in their files**.

Comment: You can get a copy of your I-94 here https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/home. What happened to you when leaving the USA is not the norm, the probability is probably less than 2% and if it happens you have your I-94 to prove you entered legally and in what status. If you're still not comfortable, you can go to a Deferred Inspection Site and see if they will stamp your passport to put your mind at rest. Read this http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87463/us-gave-me-visa-waiver-stamp-rather-than-stamp-on-visa

Comment: @SheikPaul Thanks. This helps. You can add all points you have mentioned as an answer to this questions as this answers my queries. I do not plan to go to Deferred Inspection if this stamp is not necessary. Moreover their office has only 2 hours window for walkins and is pretty far from where I work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Want to know what could be implications of missing entry stamp when I
>   travel to India next time (somewhere towards early next year)?

None. You have the I-94 as proof

> Does this impact my H1B Visa extension ?

No.

> Also what can I do to correct this information on my passport?

Nothing required to *correct*. You can contact Customs and Border Patrol for [Deferred Inspection](https://www.cbp.gov/contact/deferred-inspection/overview-deferred-inspection) if still uncomfortable and see if they will stamp your passport.

The I94 you have provides the same information, which is your entry date and status in which you entered. The stamp is NOT required. Back in the day they stamped the I-94 and attached to your passport. It was quick proof to anyone that you entered legally. They have all that information however USCIS is notoriously lazy so even when you apply for something else, they like you to provide the same evidence they have in their files.

You can get a copy of your I-94 here https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/home. The exit checks you encountered when leaving the USA is not the norm, the probability is probably less than 2% and if it happens you have your I-94 to prove you entered legally and in what status.