# Missing entry stamp into USA. Indian Passport with F1 Visa

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, passports, passport-stamps

I Travelled from DEL to EWR in Jan 2021. After Immigration in EWR, I found out that my passport is not stamped. I cross-checked the i-94 and It was updated. I'm sure that I won't face any issues in USA immigration in the future because of the valid i94 and travel records. But I'm worried about Indian Immigration. Can anyone please let me know should I get a stamped or will I face extra scrutiny with Indian Immigration? It would be really helpful to get input from people who have undergone this situation.

Thank you

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. But it might be a useful backup to download and print (or screenshot and print) your I-94 record so you have something in your hand when you arrive back in India. You might also review this: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/90741/indian-passport-missing-entry-stamp-into-usa?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Indian Passport. Missing entry stamp into USA](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/90741/indian-passport-missing-entry-stamp-into-usa)

Comment: @JackDot That question cleared most of my doubt, but my concern was whether I will face any issues while entering India.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Thank you. I have downloaded the latest i94