# US Visa with British Passport

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork, uk-citizens, study

If you have a British passport and applying for university in the US, do you need a visa or is ESTA enough?

Comment: Are you referring to the actual process of application (interview etc) or attending the university for purposes of study (eg you have actually been offered a study place)?

Answer (score 12):

You need an F-1 visa for Independent study and a J-1 visa for exchange study.

You will apply for it after having been admitted to the university and received an I-20 (for F-1) or DS-2019 (for J-1) document.

When entering the US (even when undertaking trips during your studies) always present your passport at the visa page (and **not** the ID page) as well as the I-20 or DS-2019 document. Otherwise [this might happen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87463/us-gave-me-visa-waiver-stamp-rather-than-stamp-on-visa)

Comment: You could clarify "after having been admitted": I guess you mean to the university course, rather than to the US?

Comment: @djr To the university, yes

Comment: This answer is off topic.

Comment: @phoog Not the first two paragraphs

Answer (score 7):

The terms of the visa waiver program, which govern your entry after you fly to the US using ESTA, do not permit enrollment in a university.  They also do not permit you to remain in the US for longer than 90 days.

To travel for an interview or other meetings associated with your application, however, you may indeed use the visa waiver program (and ESTA) if you qualify.

If you want to know what kinds of visa do apply in your situation, you should ask at https://expatriates.stackexchange.com.